# For Loop works not working, or giving error. Works when conditions are reversed

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I don't know if its the late hour, but I am working on the following array For Loop:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim pboxes() As PictureBox = {picMainImage, picImage2, picImage3, picImage4}

    For i As Integer = 0 To pboxes.Count - 1
        If pboxes(i).Image Is My.Resources.list Then
            pboxes(i).Image = Nothing
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The loop is supposed to check if any of the picture boxes in the array have an Image called List stored on the Resources folder in them. If it does, set the image to Nothing.  However, I run it and nothing happens., no errors, nothing.

So I reversed my For Loop as follows to see what happens:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim pboxes() As PictureBox = {picMainImage, picImage2, picImage3, picImage4}

    For i As Integer = 0 To pboxes.Count - 1
        If pboxes(i).Image Is Nothing Then
            pboxes(i).Image = My.Resources.list
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This works but is not what I want, I want the opposite.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is `My.Resources.list`?

Comment: @Bharadwaj  My.Resources.List is an image I have saved on my Resources file

Comment: Every time you access the image in your resources a **copy** will be made.  Therefore the image in your PictureBox will never "equal" the one in your resources.  I recommend you track what image is in the PictureBox in some other way.  Once possibility is to simply put a String value into the Tag property of your PictureBox.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I just looked into the Tag property and it seems like it's a good way to achieve what I want. I was not even aware of its capabilities. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is if you set the pictures in the box programatically, set `My.Resources.list` to be referenced by a global variable, ie `Public pbList = My.Resources.list`

Then, when you set the picture initially, use that variable, so: `picMainImage.Image = pbList`

Finally, in your `If` statement, you should then be able to check `If pboxes(i) is pbList Then...`

Once it becomes a variable, it seems to become static and therefore wherever you use it, it will always be the same.

EDIT: some actual code that I used a few months back:

In the module (outside sub)

```
    Public pbimage As System.Drawing.Image = My.Resources.placeholder
```

Then in the Sub

```
If imgpath <> "" Then
    Me.lblImg.ImageLocation = imgpath
Else
    Me.lblImg.ImageLocation = Nothing
    Me.lblImg.Image = pbimage
End If
```

and then this is what I use for all pictures without issues (its a function that I have run when you click on an image - if its the placeholder then you can browse for an image and save it to a data folder, otherwise it does nothing)

```
Private Sub changeImg(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles {ALL YOUR IMAGES}.Click
    If TypeOf sender Is PictureBox Then
        If DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).Image Is pbimage Then
            Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
            ofd.Title = "Please select image"
            ofd.Filter = "Image Files|*.jpg"
            If ofd.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim rn As New Random
                Dim r As Long = rn.Next(111111, 999999)
                Dim newfilename As String = My.Settings.dataPath & r.ToString & Format(Now, "ddmmyy") & ".jpg"
                Try
                    FileCopy(ofd.FileName, newfilename)
                    DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).ImageLocation = newfilename
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Check permissions to the Data folder", "Permissions error")
                End Try
            End If                
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tested this? Please update your answer with some sample code. I initially thought to try this as well but it does not work. I am curious to see this working as it is simpler than comparing pixels.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem in a program I wrote a few months back and used this as the solution. You may have to declare pbList when you load the application rather than declaring it, but once it's set it should work as intended. On my phone right now but will try and dig out the code I used when I get chance.

Comment: @JoeyJoeJoeJrShabadoo have added that sample now.

Comment: Thanks! Although your example isn't in relation to the original question this does in fact work. I obviously made a mistake when I was first looking at this approach and it is faster than comparing pixels. Jose M. really just has to add something like `Public pbImage As System.Drawing.Image = My.Resources.list` then replace `My.Resources.list` with `pbImage` when the image is being set and compared.

Comment: @JoeyJoeJoeJrShabadoo yeah the example doesn't directly fit but was doing it in a brief moment at work so didn't have time to adapt it much

Answer (score 1):

Images cannot be compared that way because the image is copied into memory and will always be different even if the pixels match. Compare the pixels directly to find out if the image is the same.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim pboxes() As PictureBox = {picMainImage, picImage2, picImage3, picImage4}

    For i As Integer = 0 To pboxes.Count - 1
        If IsSameImage(pboxes(i).Image, My.Resources.list) = True Then
            pboxes(i).Image = Nothing
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Function IsSameImage(ByVal oBitmap1 As Bitmap, ByVal oBitmap2 As Bitmap) As Boolean
    For x = 0 To oBitmap1.Width - 1
        For y = 0 To oBitmap2.Height - 1
            If Not oBitmap1.GetPixel(x, y) = oBitmap2.GetPixel(x, y) Then
                Return False
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Return True
End Function
```